# Plot point markers and lines in different hues but the same style with seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, aesthetics

Given the data frame below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "n_index": list(range(5)) * 2,
    "logic": [True] * 5 + [False] * 5,
    "value": list(range(5)) + list(range(5, 10))
})
```

I'd like to use *color and only color* to distinguish `logic` in a line plot, and mark points on `value`s. Specifically, this is my desired output (plotted by R [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org)):

```
ggplot(aes(x = n_index, y = value, color = logic), data = df) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image: desired output]

I tried to do the same thing with [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), and I specified `markers=True` but there was no marker:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.lineplot(x="n_index", y="value", hue="logic", markers=True, data=df)
```

[image: sns no markers]

I then tried adding `style="logic"` in the code, now the markers showed up:

```
sns.lineplot(x="n_index", y="value", hue="logic", style="logic", markers=True, data=df)
```

[image: sns with markers 1]

Also I tried forcing the markers to be in the same style:

```
sns.lineplot(x="n_index", y="value", hue="logic", style="logic", markers=["o", "o"], data=df)
```

[image: sns with markers 2]

It seems like that I have to specify `style` before I can have markers. However, that causes undesired plot output since I don't want to use two aesthetic dimensions on one data dimension. That violates the principles of aesthetic mapping.

Is there any way I can have the lines and points all in the same style but in different colors with `seaborn` or Python visualization? (`seaborn` is preferred - I don't like the looping way of`matplotlib`.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can directly use pandas for plotting.

**pandas via groupby**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.groupby("logic").plot(x="n_index", y="value", marker="o", ax=ax)
ax.legend(["False","True"])
```

[image]

The drawback here would be that the legend needs to be created manually.

**pandas via pivot**

```
df.pivot_table("value", "n_index", "logic").plot(marker="o")
```

[image]

**seaborn lineplot**

For seaborn lineplot it seems a single marker is enough to get the desired result.

```
sns.lineplot(x="n_index", y="value", hue="logic", data=df, marker="o")
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. According to the seaborn.lineplot documentation, `markers` should be a _boolean, list, or dictionary_, and _setting to True will use default markers_. Could it be a bug need reporting?

Comment: Note that I'm not using `markers`, but `marker`, which is a matplotlib argument and which is simply passed through to matplotlib's `plot` function. So the documentation is not wrong, is it? But your use case may be considered a missing feature. Also the fact that the legend ignores the actual artist that is drawn may be considered a bug.

Answer (score 27):

See the problem is that people are getting confused between 'markers' and 'marker'. To enable 'marker'  set 'marker='o'' not markers.

```
sns.lineplot(x=range(1,100),y=err,marker='o')
```

Comment: I think this was used in the accepted answer. Is this meant as a comment? You can comment once you have enough reputation. Otherwise explain how this is different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't gives what's the problem with the question. It doesn't explain where the user is going wrong with the approach and thus creates a confusion that may lead to user accepting the answer and using it directly without ever trying to figure out the problem in his/her code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `dashes` parameter to `False` also specify the style of the grid to `"darkgrid"`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "n_index": list(range(5)) * 2,
    "logic": [True] * 5 + [False] * 5,
    "value": list(range(5)) + list(range(5, 10))
})

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.lineplot(x="n_index", dashes=False, y="value", hue="logic", style="logic", markers=["o", "o"], data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The gray background grid/frame vanished by doing so

Answer (score 2):

You can set marker='o' in sns.linePlot to draw the marker as a circle for all the different hues, in the appropriate color.

```
sns.lineplot(x="n_index", y="value", hue="logic", marker="o", data=df)
```