# Plot list of list with different size

Tags: python, pandas, list, matplotlib, seaborn

Given a list of lists I am tryuing to plot every row in a different color, but get error:

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

```
lists = 

    0     [[44.9597, 7.7825], [44.9646, 7.7816], [45.1206, 7.7115]]
    1     [[45.0021, 7.6733], [45.003, 7.6678]]
    2     [[45.0746, 7.5985], [45.0735, 7.5956],[44.9706, 7.704],[45.0811, 7.5511]
    3     [[45.1205, 7.7116]]
```

So, in every row first number in [ ] is y and second number is x

I have tried [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236808/11852936) and [seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52385869/11852936)

Comment: Can you give some more information? Are the x-values the index and the y-values the lists? Or are the x- and y-values in each list of lists? Might also help if you could provide a plot for maybe one of the rows so we know what you're trying to make

Comment: @IanThompson ok. So, in every row first number in `[ ]` is `y` and second number is `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib`s `scatter(x,y)` function along with `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lists = np.array([[[44.9597, 7.7825], [44.9646, 7.7816], [45.1206, 7.7115]], \
                  [[45.0021, 7.6733], [45.003, 7.6678]], \
                  [[45.0746, 7.5985], [45.0735, 7.5956],[44.9706, 7.704],[45.0811, 7.5511]], \
                  [[45.1205, 7.7116]]])

plt.figure()
for l in lists:
    ar = np.array(l)  # convert to numpy array for use of indices in next line
    plt.scatter(ar[:,1], ar[:,0]) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Question says "first number is y and second number is x." Flip the scatter coordinates.

Comment: @IanThompson It didn't when I posted the answer, but: Happy now? ;)